# How to add header to axios on nuxt project for hmac authentication

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

There is a remote api and it needs hmac sha256 key which is generated with secret key and timestamp for each request.

This hmac header generation should not be seen on client code in Nuxt Project. And the requests has to be made on server side with the hmac header. For example I will send a login post request to the api. I will send password, email and hmac key as header. But this header generation code has to be hidden for the client side. And the post request should be done on server side. Not client side.

Api needs this hmac key header. To generate a hmac key, you will need a secret key which api provider gives us. you can see how hmac generation works on [this link](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online). We will put some data and timestamp. So api decrypts the key and checks the timestamp. if the timestamp delta is more than 20 second, the request will not accepted by api.

How to add this header to axios for only server side calls on axios requests and this generation script should not seen on client code ?

```
X-HMAC-TOKEN: 'hmac sha256 key generated with timestamp and secret key. and this generation script should not seen on client code'
```

[Here is an example hmac authentication example on api side](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/hmac-authentication-web-api/).

Comment: When will this token be used? What for? Because there are only specific places that can use private variables: essentially SSR only + during build time.

Comment: Each request has a lifetime 20 seconds on api side with the generated hmac key. That is for security reasons in api side. And it is hmac sha256 cypted key. So in Nuxt project it should be generated somewhere and added to all axios requests as header but only for server side requests

Comment: When will your app use those server side requests? Also, what are the settings of your Nuxt app?

Comment: For example requesting a private data from api. So api needs this hmac key. and generation hmac key needs a secret key which api provider gives us. you can see how hmac generation works on this link. we will put some data and timestamp. So api decrypts the key and checks the timestamp. if the timestamp delta is more than 20 second, the request will not accepted via api.
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online

Comment: @kissu I still have not an app. if I cannot solve this problem, I will not use Nuxt for the project

Comment: **WHEN** are you planning to make those calls exactly? Nuxt is a SSR + SPA combo by default. And not SSR only one.

Comment: @kissue I thought my question was clear. I will update the question. Some api requests will be done on server side. Not client side. And for the server side hmac key generation code has to be hidden for client side.

Comment: @kissu For example I will send a login post request to the api. I will send password, email and hmac key as header. But this header generation code has to be hidden for the client side. And the post request should be done on server side. Not on client side.

Comment: Not sure how you think of it, but you can't really hide things on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only solution looks like using server middleware and probably express.

Here is a sample code which is shared on [github](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2033#issuecomment-945200828). I just want to share the code here for everyone who has this question

First you should create server-middleware in /api folder /api/remote-api.js

```
// remote-api.js
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = require('express')();
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env.server') });

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/remote-api', (req, res) => {
  req.body.sha256_key = "whatever you specify"
  req.body.timestamp ="whatever you specify"
  axios
    .get(process.env.REMOTE_API_URL}, { 
      params: {
        term: req.query.q
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      res.json({ data: response.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.json(error);
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

then you should specify this file in nuxt.config.js

```
serverMiddleware: ['~/api/remote-api'],
```

Comment: Yeah, but this one will only work for server calls. Once you app is hydrated, you'll start using client side navigation and your call will be publicly visible (because on the client).